# How to modify property of label on AgensGraph?

Tags: agens-graph

I created new vertex on AgensGraph using CREATE statement.
How can I modify the properties of created vertex?

```
agens=# create (:v{prop:1});
GRAPH WRITE (INSERT VERTEX 1, INSERT EDGE 0)
agens=# match (n:v{prop:1}) return n;
         n         
-------------------
 v[3.1]{"prop": 1}
(1 row)
```

I want to following result after modifying vertex.

```
agens=# match (n:v{prop:2}) return n;
         n         
-------------------
 v[3.1]{"prop": 2}
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

MATCH (a {prop:1})
SET a.prop=2;

--will do